# Version number in filename

Tags: c#

At work we have a tracing library that has to be referenced for all applications.

Recently following a major version change, the trace lib name changed as well

From

```
dotnet_tracing-w32r-1-2
```

To

```
dotnet_tracing-w32r-2-0
```

This broke several of our pre-packaged solutions (projects that have a main branch that get forked for customization to specific customers).

What I'm trying to figure out, is there any way to (auto-magically) reference one OR the other? Having the version in the filename is screwing everything up and I really dont want to maintain two separate branches of these projects.

Comment: You may use links (hard-links) to create another entry in the filesystem which points to the same file. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, we used [Conditional References](http://blog.davidjwise.com/2012/07/24/conditional-library-references-in-visual-studio/)

First I created 2 different build configurations - and based upon those build configurations, I used conditional references to reference the proper assembly. Finally we then use some post build scripting to generate our 2 different NuGet Packages and publish to our NuGet feed.

Comment: Also - this is highly symptomatic of us using the IDE as our build environment. I probably would have known this ahead of time if we used a dedicated build environment.